# Sum of squares in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

I have to do a short presentation of the Clojure language and in it I must also supply the solution for the simple task: **Input an integer number n and output the sum: 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2. Use input validation for n to be positive.**

I have zero previous xp with Lisp dialects or Java and I find this kind of challenging. How far off am I? (guessing a LOT):

```
(defn sum_of_squares [n]
(if (> n 0)
    (def sum 0)
    (dotimes [n]
        (+ sum (* n n)))))
```

As you can see I have no idea what's going on. How should I actually prompt the user to enter the value of **n** and later **println** the total sum? Also where is the whole **(+ sum (* n n)** expression supposed to store it's result, updating sum in the process?

Maybe there's a LOT simpler way of solving this problem, so feel free to show me : ).

Comment: How about a look at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares#Clojure)? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple functional solution:

```
(defn sum-of-squares [n] 
  (reduce + (map #(* % %) (range 1 (inc n)))))
```

Reading from the inside out to see how this works:

- Take the `range` from 1 to n (use `(inc n)` as the upper bound since you want to include n itself)
- `map` a function `#(* % %)`, which is just an anonymous function that squares its argument. This has the effect of squaring all the numbers in the sequence.
- `reduce` the sequence with `+` - i.e. add all the squares together to get your result.

Comment: Yes, that's what was previously suggested and what I've actually ended up using + including an if condition as that is part of my task. Thanks for your answer and also for explaining exactly how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not really the kind of place for these questions, but this being a Clojure question and I not being able to resist my self, let me give it a shot:

```
(defn sum-of-squares [n] (reduce (fn [memo x] (+ memo (* x x))) (range (inc n))))
```

Also when you are dealing with a functional language, think immutability. Don't complect[1]. Once you initialize something don't try to change it unless done using thread safety in mind. Clojure makes this easy with refs, atoms. A very relevant video would be Rich Hickey's - "Simple Made Easy"[1] talk on the same subject.

Comment: You should add something like `{:pre  [(> n 0)]}` for the input validation

Comment: Wouldn't it just return `0`?

Comment: (reduce + ...) rather than (apply + ...) though. Not that apply doesn't work, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: @Cubic: I tend to agree that `reduce` is more elegant, but the apply with more than a couple of arguments *is* a reduce after that.

Comment: essentially the same but I think a little cleaner: `(defn sum-of-squares [n] (reduce + (map #(* % %) (range (inc n)))))`

Comment: @Kevin: looks much cleaner thanks.. Feel free to edit the main answer itself! :)

Comment: @Kevin and OP: Thanks for the answers. Particularly Kevin's code shouldn't be that hard for me to explain, even though they both work fine : ). From just two answers I moved from not knowing a thing, to actually having a clue of how Functional Programming actually works. Functional Programming seems like a blast ;D

Comment: Or `(defn ss [n] {:pre [(> n 0)]} (/ (* n (inc n) (inc (* n 2))) 6))`?

Comment: @A.Webb: You deserve special points for an analytical solution!